# Faster Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-due

I am using Arduino Mega 2560 for interfacing devices such as the [Maxim MAX22500E](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX22500E-MAX22501E.pdf) and [TI ADS1241](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ADS1241).

Now I am requiring more speed for hopefully the same coding, and I am thinking in the Arduino Due (84 MHz Clock) which is enough faster than the Arduino Mega (16MHz Clock) but imposes working with 3.3V, hence using some 3.3V 5V [level conversion](https://next-hack.com/index.php/2017/09/15/how-to-interface-a-5v-output-to-a-3-3v-input/) for every input and output.

If I want to keep the same "arduino" coding environment, is there another faster 5V processor? Or should I focus in the strategy of interfacing the 5V devices from a 3.3V processor?

Comment: There are "unofficial" Arduino ports to the popular STM32 micro controllers, which feature 5V tolerant pins (but can't output 5V). Apart from that, Majenko is right, 5V is hardly needed anymore - otherwise, there wouldn't be so many 3.3V-controllers!

Comment: _"... Arduino Due (84 MHz Clock) which is enough faster than the Arduino Mega (16MHz Clock) ..."_ - Note that you can't just compare clock speeds across _vastly_ different processors like that. The Mega has an 8-bit AVR microcontroller, the Due has a 32-bit ARM core. In this case, it's likely the speed difference is larger than the clock speed difference suggests, but in general that's not an assumption you can make.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should begin working with 3.3V. 5V is getting rarer and rarer as far as "real world" applications go.

Many devices that you have been using at 5V will also work at 3.3V (such as the MAX22500E). Running those at 3.3V will mean you don't need logic level translation.

Others, like the ADS1241, have "split power" where you can have different logic voltage (DV<sub>DD</sub>) and analog voltage (AV<sub>DD</sub>), so you just run the logic at 3.3V and the analog at 5V so you don't need a logic level translator.

For those few rare devices that have to run at 5V and don't have a 3.3V equivalent, yes you will need to use some logic level shifting.

Comment: Thanks. That was the kind of guidance i was needing... I will go fully into 3.3V...